# How do I 'comb' through a list to find certain strings?

Tags: python

I am doing python courses online, and was wondering how to search through a list to find out if two strings were identical (Taking out the fact of capitalization and whatnot)

[This is What It's supposed to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj1AL.png)

And this is [What it does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd3se.png)
The goal is to "Write a program where you can enter one word at a time, and be told how many unique words you have entered. You should not count duplicates. The program should stop asking for more words when you enter a blank line."
And i've written this. But i'm confused on how to stop duplicates from getting past.

```
word = input('Word: ')
uniqueWords = word.split()
wordCounter = 0
while word:
  word = input('Word: ')
  wordCounter = wordCounter + 1
  uniqueWords.append(word)
print('You know', wordCounter, 'unique word(s)!')
```

Comment: Have you tried anything till now? Can you share your attempt?

Comment: you mean two string inside the list? a simple approach would be to sort the list(alphabetically) and check every adjacent pair

Comment: can you provide an example of what you want to do?

Comment: The goal is to make something like this: `Word: Chat
Word: Chien
Word: Chat
Word: Escargot
Word: 
You know 3 unique word(s)!`

Comment: This is my attempt so far:`word = input('Word: ')
uniqueWords = word.split()
wordCounter = 0
while word:
  word = input('Word: ')
  wordCounter = wordCounter + 1
  uniqueWords.append(word)
print('You know', wordCounter, 'unique word(s)!')
print(uniqueWords)` But i'm unsure of how to check on if words are the same

Comment: Yeah ... as you see, comments are not really meant for this all. See that ***[edit]*** button right below your question? So use it. But you might wanta read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and possibly [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want, using `set` :

```
uniqueWords = set()
word = input('Word: ')
uniqueWords.update(word.split())
while word:
    word = input('Word: ')
    uniqueWords.update(word.split())
print('You know {} unique word(s)!'.format(len(uniqueWords)))
print(uniqueWords)
```

Output :

```
Word: a b
Word: c d
Word: e
Word:
You know 5 unique word(s)!
{'c', 'a', 'e', 'b', 'd'}
```